# parsing in memory xml in python

Tags: python, xml-parsing, marklogic

I'm trying to parse XML which is in memory (not in file). How can get value of `<id>`.

```py
xmldoc="""
<forest-counts xsi:schemaLocation="http://marklogic.com/manage/forests manage-forests.xsd" xmlns="http://marklogic.com/manage/forests" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <id>10110137205746170621</id>
  <name>testdb1</name>
<forest-counts>
"""
```

I can't use BS due to some restrictions. Any other solutions will be appreciated.

For MarkLogic experts:
I'm trying to get forest-id programmatically. If there any other solution then it would be fine.

Comment: This is interesting. Sooo, if I might ask, what differentiates the process of using regex against something in memory vs. in a file? Trying to avoid giving you a useless answer.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done a whole lot of XML parsing in Python recently, but if the only thing you want is the forest ID, you can get that from the REST Management API in JSON.

```
curl -s --anyauth -u admin:admin "http://localhost:8002/manage/v2/forests?format=json"
```

This is one of the few examples where it's a bit frustrating that the ID is not returned in the resource properties. But it's in the JSON structure returned from the list endpoint.

Here's a jq query that would find the forest ID of the testdb1 forest:

```
jq ".\"forest-default-list\".\"list-items\".\"list-item\"[] | select(.nameref==\"testdb1\") | .idref"
```

Note that the representation of the forest ID is a string in JSON even though it's a number. This avoids numeric overflow issues for very large random ID values.